# Google Map JS API - map tiles load but all images (markers, zoom control, etc.) don't load for 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, knockout.js

I am using google maps api 3 (JS) and everything is working...sort of, there is a significant issue plaguing me from getting this released.  The map loads and displays on the page as I would expect. However all images, the zoom controls the google logo in the lower left corner and the push pin images all do not load for 2 minutes consistently every time the page loads. I have watched the page load in chrome dev tools and the entire page loads, then sits for 2 minutes then the remaining 7 images load out of the blue after 2 minutes with no other item in the list showing that it could have stalled or have been blocking the requests. I am getting the same results from PC's android phones etc. using Internet Explorer and Chrome web browsers. I have also tested this from our private network as well as other networks (personal and public) Please help. Thanks in advance!

Here is some of my code:

Generate api script in page head:

```
// Setup google maps JS file
var script = document.createElement('script');
var asyncAttr = document.createAttribute('async');
var deferAttr = document.createAttribute('defer');
script.setAttributeNode(asyncAttr);
script.setAttributeNode(deferAttr);
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.src = _googleMapJsPath;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Which generates (no key for localhost - key is present on server):

```
<script async defer type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Then I do not use the callback in the query string as I need to wait to setup the map until required. Instead the map is initialized when needed:

```
self.currentMap = new google.maps.Map(self.element, {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false
});
```

Set markers:

```
$.each(newMap.points, function (index, item) {
    if (item.latitude != 0 && item.longitude != 0) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: item.latitude, lng: item.longitude},
            map: self.currentMap,
            optimized: false
        });

        self.markers.push(marker);
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML element:

```
<div id="mapDiv" class="map-container"></div>
```

Here is the CSS for the class on the DIV:

```
.map-container {
    width: 580px;
    height: 580px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried decreasing the number of markers/images being loaded? See if it will also decrease the time it takes to load them?

Comment: This is with only a single point/marker being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening only on your computer or multiple devices, browsers? It will be odd answer but I have disabled firebug and it worked fine for me if you have firebug is on. 
Also since I don't see your code where do you have your JScript files top or bottom ? That may change the priorities. I am just guessing by what you have provided so far.

Comment: This is happening from every device I have tested from (PC's phones etc.). I am not using firebug. The google api script is at the top of the page in the head and my code implementing the map is at the bottom. I am not using a callback in the api script query string, as I have to load the map when needed not all the time and on load.

Answer (score 0):

We have figured out that this problem is specific to our custom JS framework used for this application. We have the maps working as expected on 2 out of 3 pages. We just have to correct the hang up issue on the 1 problem page. Thank you all!